# CSS Transform 3D - get children if main SVG to face the camera

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-transforms, gsap

I am making an animation using the GreenSock JS animation library. In the animation there are 3d transformations on SVGs.

The current case is: I have a larger SVG (with paths, polylines, etc.) animated (3d transformations and others), and I want some SVG elements (children of the main SVG) to always face the "camera" (the screen), while they go with the main SVG (e.g. their location on the screen, their size / scale changes with the transformation, but the rotation does not)?

Here is an image:
[how it should look like during the animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOOe9.png).

I have tried transforming them (the district numbers and highway signs) in the opposite direction as their parent (the main SVG) is transformed, but it only seems to work with the Z axis.

```
var tl_loc1 = new TimelineMax({
  repeat: -1,
  yoyo: true
});

tl_loc1
  .fromTo($("#City_Glow"), 4, {
    css: {
    scale: 1.3,
      transformPerspective: 200,
      transformStyle: "preserve-3d",
      rotationY: -90,
      rotationX: 60,
      rotationZ: 20,
      opacity: 0,
      top: "-300px",
    }
  }, {
    css: {
      scale: 1,
      transformPerspective: 200,
      transformStyle: "preserve-3d",
      rotationY: 0,
      rotationX: 0,
      rotationZ: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      top: "0",
    }
  })
  .fromTo($(".loc1-cls-7, .loc1-cls-6"), 4, {
    css: {
      transformStyle: "preserve-3d",
      rotationY: 90,
      rotationX: -60,
      rotationZ: -20,
    }
  }, {
    css: {
      transformStyle: "preserve-3d",
      rotationY: 0,
      rotationX: 0,
      rotationZ: 0,
    }
  }, 0);
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/mukagergely/pen/QEvyqR

I do not know if it is impossible to achieve with CSS transform3d, GreenSock has some issues, or it's just me not knowing the solution.

Comment: You can apply 3D CSS transforms to root `<svg>` elements, but not the elements inside them.  Proper support may come eventually, but browsers have little to no support for it now.  You will probably have to move your labels outside the SVG and manipulate them as HTML elements.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, and the idea. At the GreenSock forum they pointed me towards three.js: http://greensock.com/forums/topic/14664-animate-3d-with-greensock-separate-animation-for-children/